# Прочитать popen

Tags: php

Есть следующий код:

```
$result = '';
$connect = popen('sleep 5 && echo ok &','r');
while (!feof($connect)) {
        $result .= fread($connect, 8192);
}
echo $result;
```

Хочу получить пустую строку в случае если ещё ничего нет в STDOUT. Таким образом смогу периодически опрашивать `$connect` на наличие результата. Проблема в том, что `fread` ждет вывода (в данном случае 5 сек).

Есть идеи как это сделать?

Comment: тут почитайте, http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-notification-callback.php если что-то будет непонятно спрашивайте,  только не "мне вообще ничего непонятно" а конкретный вопрос плз. В общем если вы знакомы с perl это реализует что-то вроде IO:Select

Comment: Мне нужно установить соединение с хостом. Ответ может поступить через час. Необходимо установить соединение и выполнять другой код, между делом опрашивая статус соединения(пришел ответ или нет). В данном случае file_get content будет ожидать ответа сколько потребуется, что собственно мне и нужно обойти. Тем более мне нужны заголовки, а я могу получить только тело ответа. Этот вариант красивый и я узнал много нового, но заданную задачу мне решить неполучилось. Может я чего-то не знаю?

Comment: так вам нужно  curl чтобы заголовки читать, и да - с помощью stream notification callback по идее можно читать поток curl.

Comment: Начал писать ответ перед тем как вы добавили комментарий)) Я и так дергаю курлом. В примере я просто отобразил задержку. Вы имеете ввиду обрабатывать события контекста? Я так и не смог получить результирующее сообщение, хотя ошибки и статус обрабатываются нормально. Можете написать пример кода на основании этой функции?

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу:

```
$result = '';
$connect = popen('sleep 5 && echo ok &','r');
$stream = array($connect);
// выясняем готов ли стрим
if(stream_select($stream, $w = null, $e = null, 1)) {
    // получаем ответ
    $result = stream_get_contents($this->connect, -1, 0);
    pclose($this->connect);
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: вот сюда посмотрите про curl, вроде есть у них и async и callback.
https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/2362936 хотя, по моему они тож не передают управление в главную программу...

Comment: У них практически тот-же функционал, только реализован по другому. Я решил свою задачу. Спасибо!